# How to extract specific rows and columns of a Matrix where a max occurs

Tags: r

```
M5.7.2<-matrix(sample(1:4,16,replace=TRUE),nrow=4,ncol=4)
Q5.7.2<-function(X, rownum=FALSE){
  if(rownum==TRUE)
    z <-(1:nrow(X))[apply(X == max(X),1,any)]
 
  x<-which(M5.7.2 == max(M5.7.2), arr.ind = TRUE)
  list(z,x,M5.7.2)
  

}
Q5.7.2(M5.7.2,TRUE)
```

I'm trying to get it to return the indices as well as the values in the rows and columns where the maximum value occurs. I've tried a few methods to subset the rows and columns where the maximum occurs but I cannot figure it help. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This code now prints results for the case where there are more than one maximum.

I have modified your function a little to select the x-th value from X. I believe this is what you were hoping to find. In order to output it how you want the function will need to be reworked hopefully it is clear how to do this from the code I have posted.

```r
M5.7.2<-matrix(sample(1:4,16,replace=TRUE),nrow=4,ncol=4)
Q5.7.2<-function(X, rownum=FALSE){
  if(rownum==TRUE)
    z <-(1:nrow(X))[apply(X == max(X),1,any)]
  
  x<-which(M5.7.2 == max(M5.7.2), arr.ind = TRUE)
  
  # Select the value
  v <-X[x]

  # Print the results of the indices and the max value we obtained
  for(i in 1:length(v)) {
    print(paste("Indices: row", x[i, 1], "column", x[i, 2], "Value", v[i]))
  }
}

Q5.7.2(M5.7.2,TRUE)
#> [1] "Indices: row 2 column 3 Value 4"
#> [1] "Indices: row 1 column 4 Value 4"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The code won't return the indices for multiple maximum values, It only returns the first maximum values row and column indices. For eg if you use 
`set.seed(2)
`M5.7.2<-matrix(sample(1:8,16,replace=TRUE),nrow=4,ncol=4)`

you get `"Indices: row 1 column 2 Value 8" "Indices: row 1 column 2 Value 8"` If you look you get a max in row 1 and 2

Comment: I have updated the  code to account for multiple maxima. I hadn't considered this case originally.